# How can I average every 2n element of a list?

Tags: r, list, average

I have a list of 86 values, where each two listed are results of one sample. I am measuring 43 samples.

Eg (abbrv)

```
   5.157
4.266
5.118
5.473
4.909
5.093
```

I am trying to get this end result

```
4.7115
5.2955
5.001
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I would recommend you to read this [guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have already tried to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We create a grouping variable with `gl` and use group by `mean`

```
unname(tapply(v1,  as.integer(gl(length(v1), 2, length(v1))), FUN = mean))
#[1] 4.7115 5.2955 5.0010
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(5.157, 4.266, 5.118, 5.473, 4.909, 5.093)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add an index column.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, mean = 10, sd = 2))

df %>% 
  mutate(index = rep(1:(nrow(df)/2), each = 2)) %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  summarise(xMean = mean(x)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

output:

```
  index xMean
  <int> <dbl>
1     1  9.21
2     2 11.6 
3     3 11.8 
4     4  9.20
5     5  8.87
```